# How does one express $0.0\overline{1410}$ as a fraction?

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

How does one express $0.0\overline{1410}$ as a fraction? I know the answer is $141/9999$ but I am not sure how to derive it using some formula from below.

> Wikipedia says assume $x=0.a_1a_2...a_n.$
>
> $10^nx=a_1a_2...a_n.\overline{a_1a_2...a_n}$
>
> $(10^{n}-1)x=99...99x=a_1a_2...a_n$
>
> $x=\dfrac{a_1a_2..._n}{10^n-1}=\dfrac{a_1a_2...a_n}{99...99}$

What to do when $a_4=0$?

In our case where $n=4$, the length of the repetend.

$10^{n}x=141.0\overline{1410}.$

$(10^{n}-1)x=141$

$9999x=141$

$x=141/9999$

Comment: If you want to follow the rules, do it with $0.\overline{1410}$ and divide by an additional $10$, should be $\frac{1410}{99990}$, which reduces to $\frac{141}{9999}$. Or, note that in this case in particular, you can use $0.0\overline{1410} = 0.\overline{0141}$, and you'll get $\frac{0141}{9999}=\frac{141}{9999}$ directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, here's the process you can take. Say you have some decimal with $n$ non-repeating digits followed by $m$ repeating digits:

$$ 0.x_1 \cdots x_n\overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} . $$

Then, you can split this into a sum of two decimals:

$$ 0.x_1 \cdots x_n\overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} = 0.x_1 \cdots x_n + 0.\underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{n \ 0's} \ \overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} . $$

Then, the first decimal is

$$ 0.x_1 \cdots x_n = \frac{x_1 \cdots x_n}{10^n} , $$

and the second decimal is

$$ 0.\underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{n \ 0's} \ \overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} = \frac{1}{10^n}\cdot 0.\overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} . $$

You can use the same logic you quoted from Wikipedia in the question above to show that

$$ 0.\overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} = \frac{y_1 \cdots y_m}{\underbrace{9 \cdots 9}_{m \ 9's}} = \frac{y_1 \cdots y_m}{10^m - 1} . $$

Then, our second decimal from the sum above is

$$ 0.\underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{n \ 0's} \ \overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} = \frac{y_1 \cdots y_m}{10^n\left(10^m-1\right)} . $$

Summing these fractions, we have

$$ 0.x_1 \cdots x_n\overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} = \frac{x_1 \cdots x_n}{10^n} + \frac{y_1 \cdots y_m}{10^n\left(10^m-1\right)} , $$

or in terms of the digits, this is

$$ 0.x_1 \cdots x_n\overline{y_1 \cdots y_m} = \frac{x_1 \cdots x_n}{1\underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{n \ 0's}} + \frac{y_1 \cdots y_m}{\underbrace{9 \cdots 9}_{m \ 9's}\underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{n \ 0's}} .$$

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy and done "mechanically", e.g,
$$0.123\overline{45678}
=\frac{12345678-123}{99999000}.$$
In your case
$$0.0\overline{1410}
=\frac{1410-0}{99990}.$$